# Extending Google Maps Android API v2 to provide pan and zoom events

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I extend Google Maps Android API v2 to detect when the Map has been panned or zoomed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add an [`OnCameraChangeListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener) to your [`GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap) via `setOnCameraChangeListener()`.

Comment: Thank you! The previous API didn't have a native option to this.